# meteorite unable to add from atmosphere

Tags: meteor, meteorite

### **ORIGINAL QUESTION -- FIXED see below**

I've been having trouble using mrt on my MacOS X 10.7.5 box to install atmosphere packages with an error about a version.  Looks like it is set to "*" whereas the meteorite code is looking for it to be numeric.  Versions are all current as shown below.  Any suggestions what's happening or how to correct?

```
$ mrt add balanced-payments

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:60
    throw('Version should begin with a number: ' + version);
                                               ^
Version should begin with a number: *

$ uname -a
Darwin mini-en0.home 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ node --version
v0.10.19

$ meteor --version
Release 0.6.6.1

$ mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.6.14
```

### **SOLUTION**

This was caused by the balanced-payments smart package specifying "*" as the version of sync -methods required.  This would cause all future mrt commands to fail, presumably due to some logic that always tries to satisfy the dependencies.

[balanced-payments/smart.json]:  The *incorrect* snippet is ...

```
  "packages": {
    "sync-methods": "*"
  }
```

Changing `"*"` to `{}` for the sync-methods version requirement fixes the error:

[balanced-payments/smart.json]:

```
{
  "name": "balanced-payments-ext",
  "description": "Balanced Payments API packaged for meteor",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-balanced-payments",
  "author": "Ian Serlin <ian@ianserlin.com>",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "git": "https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-balanced-payments.git",
  "packages": {
    "sync-methods": {}
  }
}
```